# Binding array that contains custom struct cannot infer type

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So I have this iOS binding method with xamarin that uses array of custom struct that is defined in structs.cs file. However, the type cannot be inferred implicitly so it returns that error:

```
the type ColorHSV must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method.
```

With CGPoint I had this same problem but I managed to fix it by using (BindAs) mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference#bindasattribute
but ColorHSV is custom struct so it can not use BindAs type :/

**ApiDefinition.cs**

```cs
namespace arFramework {
    // @interface ArPainting : NSObject
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface ArPainting
    {
        // -(UIImage *)processImage:(UIImage *)image :(int)resolution :(int)pointsSize :(const CGPoint *)points :(struct ColorHSV *)colors :(float)maxSliderValue :(_Bool)indoor :(_Bool)live :(float)transparency;
        [Export("processImage:::::::::")]
        UIImage ProcessImage(UIImage image, int resolution, int pointsSize, [BindAs(typeof(CGPoint[]))] NSValue[] points, ColorHSV[] colors, float maxSliderValue, bool indoor, bool live, float transparency);
    }
}
```

**Structs.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace arFramework
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ColorHSV
    {
        public float hue;

        public float saturation;

        public float value;
    }
}
```

**Generated code that produces error (.g.cs)**

```cs
public virtual global::UIKit.UIImage ProcessImage (global::UIKit.UIImage image, int resolution, int pointsSize, [BindAs (typeof (CGPoint[]), OriginalType = typeof (NSValue[]))] CGPoint[] points, ColorHSV[] colors, float maxSliderValue, bool indoor, bool live, float transparency)
        {
            var image__handle__ = image!.GetNonNullHandle (nameof (image));
            if (points is null)
                ObjCRuntime.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (nameof (points));
            if (colors is null)
                ObjCRuntime.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (nameof (colors));
            var nsb_points = NSArray.FromNSObjects (o => NSValue.FromCGPoint (o), points);
            var nsa_colors = NSArray.FromNSObjects (colors); // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
            global::UIKit.UIImage? ret;
            if (IsDirectBinding) {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<global::UIKit.UIImage> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_int_int_IntPtr_IntPtr_float_bool_bool_float (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("processImage:::::::::"), image__handle__, resolution, pointsSize, nsb_points.GetHandle (), nsa_colors.Handle, maxSliderValue, indoor, live, transparency))!;
            } else {
                ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<global::UIKit.UIImage> (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_int_int_IntPtr_IntPtr_float_bool_bool_float (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("processImage:::::::::"), image__handle__, resolution, pointsSize, nsb_points.GetHandle (), nsa_colors.Handle, maxSliderValue, indoor, live, transparency))!;
            }
            nsb_points?.Dispose ();nsa_colors.Dispose ();
            return ret!;
        }
```

**Signature (.h)**

```cpp
- (UIImage *) processImage: (UIImage *) image
                          : (int) resolution
                          : (int) pointsSize
                          : (const CGPoint []) points
                          : (struct ColorHSV []) colors
                          : (float) maxSliderValue
                          : (bool) indoor
                          : (bool) live
                          : (float) transparency;
```

Comment: 1) Please provide your code as text, not as image. It's pretty annoying to follow a bunch of links to understand your code. 2) Can you show the signature of the method you're calling?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I replaced images with source code, sorry about that!

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Fixed those problems that you mentioned, and is that header file signature what you asked?